# How can I play a `mpeg` file in `MFC`

Tags: c++, mfc, mpeg

How can I play a `mpeg` file in `MFC`.

Can you tell me any function which can play this type of files.

Comment: I dont know whether the following link gives a thread to your query http://rauf-thecoder.blogspot.com/2011/06/media-in-element.html

Comment: that is WPF... I asked abt MFC

Comment: That y i used the term 'a thread to'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed windows media player in your application, either by [using an ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [IWMPPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563514%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. Or by using borland's [TMediaPlayer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/MPlayer.TMediaPlayer). An example can be found [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/MediaPlayer_%28C++%29). I would recommend to stick to the first variant (an ActiveX control) if you want to work in MFC as MFC and Borland C++ builder are not an optimal combination.

Answer (score 1):

DirectShow and Video For Windows have no wrapper classes in MFC. Therefore, you will need to use the bare Win32 API (alongside MFC window classes) to use either software playing API.